# Socket Appender in Log4j2 giving error

Tags: java, xml, sockets, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to use a SocketAppender in a project which uses log4j2 for logging. When I add the configrations for Socket and deploy the application, it throws a parsing error.
Below are the details.

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" strict="true" packages="">
<Appenders>
 <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

 </Console>
 <Socket name="Socket1" host="localhost" port="4712"  reconnectionDelay="5000">
        <SerializedLayout/>
</Socket>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.example.web" level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="Socket1"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="DEBUG" />
    </Root>

</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

POM.XML:

```
<!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
 <version>2.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
```

Exception on deploying the project in Tomcat:

```
log4j:WARN Fatal parsing error 31 and column 6
log4j:WARN Premature end of file.
log4j:ERROR Could not parse url   [file:/apps/work/Catalina/example/loader/log4j.xml].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse  (DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$2.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:767)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:866)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

It works if I remove the Socket related changes from log4j2.xml.
Could anyone please guide on the right way to add Socket Appender?
Or find any issues in above configuration.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your problem is not related to Log4j2 configuration file, but with your Log4j (v1) configuration file (`/apps/work/Catalina/example/loader/log4j.xml`) that Spring seems to use. We can see `org.apache.log4j` in the stack trace, which is clearly Log4j v1 (Log4j v2 is more like `org.apache.logging.log4j`).

You may want to post your Log4j v1 file (`/apps/work/Catalina/example/loader/log4j.xml`) here so that we can help you if you don't manage to fix the error syntax in this configuration file.

PS: I've tried your `log4j2.xml` file and it works great. You may want to replace `status="INFO"` with `status="trace"` in your Log4j2 configuration file to get more debug info in the console (eg. socket error, bad log4j2 config, ...)

Comment: Hi thanks for noticing that!! Do you think we need to add any log4j2 related jar to tomcat's /lib folder?

Comment: Well, I don't know if log4j2 JARs are missing (you would not take any risk to try to add these JARs), I just said that in your case, Spring didn't manage to log anything due to a bad Log4j (v1) configuration file. Log4j2 didn't complain at all from what I can see. Maybe Log4j2 works but you think it doesn't due to Log4j v1 error... If it doesn't work, you may want to replace `status="INFO"` with `status="trace"` in your Log4j2 configuration file to get more debug info in the console. Also, check that someone is listening on port 4712 before app starts, or it will not work

Comment: This answer has just been down-voted, can we know why?